# Midi track meta event values which do not conform to the specification

Tags: midi

Hi I have scraped a large number of midi files off the internet. 
I am using them for training material to train a generative adversarial network. I find that many midi files conform to the midi standard but then I run into issues with midi meta events with values of FF11 and FF10 . I have looked up the midi specification from several sources and have never found midi meta events defined in this way. Here is the hex of a midi track event with some of the offending values:
4D 54 72 6B 00 00 1A 8D 00 FF 03 0D 47 75 69 74
61 72 20 44 41 44 47 41 44 00 **FF 10** 08 00 00 3E
39 37 32 2D 26 00 C0 19 00 C1 19 00 B0 65 00 00
B0 64 00 00 B0 06 02 00 B0 65 7F 00 B0 64 7F 00
E0 00 40 00 B1 65 00 00 B1 64 00 00 B1 06 02 00
B1 65 7F 00 B1 64 7F 00 E1 00 40 00 B0 0A 3F 00
B1 0A 3F 00 B0 5D 10 00 B0 5B 1E 00 B1 5D 10 00
B1 5B 1E 81 69 **FF 11** 01 00 00 90 3E 51 08 **FF 11**

I cant seem to find any information whatsoever on these values even though these midi files play over timidity and other midi player software perfectly. Can anyone point me to some information about them and what they mean? any help would be greatly , greatly appreciated. :-) resolving this issue would be a service to the miriad of people who are trying to use the python-midi library to train tensorflow models and this I am sure is only a fraction of the people who would be effected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [SMF specification](https://www.midi.org/specifications/item/standard-midi-files-smf) says:

> As with chunks, future meta-events may be designed which may not be known to existing programs, so programs must properly ignore meta-events which they do not recognize, and indeed, should *expect* to see them.

I am not aware of any published extension that defines values 10h or 11h; it's likely that some sequencer uses these for its own purposes, and violated the specification by not using type 7F for that.